# Top users page columns are confusing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-users

When viewing tag's top users ([Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) for example), we get two columns of numbers, followed by users banners:

[image: top users]

Only after hovering over labels we can see that the left column is the "total score" and the right one is the "# of answers provided". I don't know if it's only me, but I find this a bit confusing.

Can we think of alternative way of displaying this information? Maybe by adding a small label explaining the numbers?

Comment: Some column headings would be nice

Comment: Jon Skeet does not require a column header. He *is* the column header.

Comment: YEA! ME! I made the list, ass last but still on the list! :-)

Comment: I actually took a different screenshot, but when I uploaded it....... Jon Skeet appeared.

Comment: For reference, every top users list will show you at the bottom so you have an idea of how you fare with regards to the others. It doesn't necessarily mean anyone else sees you on the list or that you "made the list" per se.

Comment: and there goes Jarrod's 15 seconds of fame ;)

Comment: If Jon Skeet isn't on the top users list of any given tag it means his reputation in that tag is larger than the system can hold. SO please fix!